# How to get file generation datetime and updated datetime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, file-io

I am trying to generate files and perform write operation in a scheduled process.  I need to find out the time taken to generate the files (after write operation is performed).  I am little confused in this operation.  Can anyone help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `CreationTime` and `LastWriteTime` and find their differences.

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo("C:\test.text");
Console.WriteLine(file.LastWriteTime);
Console.WriteLine(file.CreationTime);

var timeTaken = file.LastWriteTime - file.CreationTime;
```